# RecyclerView with FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, floating-action-button

I have an activity that has a `RecyclerView` (optionally in a `CardView`) and a `FloatingActionButton`

I want the FAB to be always on screen at the bottom right, but when I scroll to the end of the `RecyclerView`, the FAB is hiding part of the content on the last item.

Using `android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"` on the parent `CardView` (or the `RecyclerView` itself after removing the `CardView`) fixes that issue, but it causes the `RecyclerView` to shrink to the screen size minus the `48dp` margin.

I want the `RecyclerView` to be full size (i.e. fits all items), but when I scroll over the items until I reach the last item, there should be that margin so that the FAB does not cover the last item of the `RecyclerView`. That is similar to the behavior of the email list in the Google Inbox/Gmail app.

I have seen many questions with similar (but not same) problem, but none of the solutions worked for me. I know there should be some easy fix for this problem, and I don't want to extend `LinearLayoutManager`, as it seems too much for this problem. I also don't want to hide the FAB on scroll.

Here is what I have so far:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/card_list"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**card_list.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Remove the layout_marginBottom from the CardView and add the following to the RecyclerView:

```
android:paddingBottom="48dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Comment: Actually, I am using `layout_marginBottom`. `paddingBottom` was from one of the trials. Updated the question. Tried your suggestion with and without `layout_marginBottom` but it only added extra white space at the end of the `RecyclerView`

Comment: Sorry @A.A. it's clipToPadding="false" (not "true"). I edited my answer.

Comment: That's very close to what I want, but there is still white space at the end of the list. I want this space to show the background of the `CoordinatorLayout` instead

Comment: @A.A. I guess you could play with the background of the RecyclerView (set some transparency maybe) and the background of its items to have what you want.

Comment: This works great...until the SnackBar pushes the FAB up but not the RecyclerView. Anyone have a solution for this? Does some behavior need to be added to the RecyclerView in the CoordinatorLayout?